# Adding a custom field that contains a few different field types

Tags: 8

Trying to figure out how to create a custom field type that is a bundle of individual fields. I want to do this specific field in a native way.

At a minimum, each row needs to provide:

- Entity Reference field (to User)
- Text plain (for published name)
- Formatted text (no summary need)

The field itself will be unlimited cardinality.

I initially built this as an extension of the `EntityReferenceItem` field, but now that I need to add the formatted text field (new requirement), this does not seem right anymore.

Is this a simple endeavor or should I just use Paragraphs? I wanted to go the native route because to change the storage now would mean a change in the way migration definitions are scripted to change how the data would be captured (by switching to Paragraphs) which I would like to avoid doing (means redoing work, tests, etc).

There will be a Solr search consideration here as well - and I would like these same UIDs to be facets. Would Paragraph on the node also support this?

Comment: A downvote? No explanation? What am I missing?

Comment: +1, this is a very good question. Compound fields are a weak side of Drupal because it needs some effort to create one. Paragraphs are not always a good replacement because of the huge overhead. If you switch the compound field to be based on a formatted text field type/formatter/widget you can use ckeditor. But no longer an autocomplete widget for the reference property, unless you manage somehow to combine both field types. I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: Yep. Paragraph in normal circumstances would make it a cheap addition. But there are some edge cases here I am thinking about that seems like you should be able to create these sorts of things with the internal Field API. I feel like I am going to pay this cost later with Solr and Facets, for example, and having a hard time drilling into that data.

Comment: You might consider field_collections.  The 8.3 dev version is still active.  Another alternative might be to use the entity construction kit (eck) to create a lightweight entity with the fields you want.  Then use inline entity form to manage them.

Comment: In those two cases, how does that differ from Paragraphs? My concern is the degrees of separation and load overhead that comes with it. The site will already have Paragraphs (in other areas).